# Large database design

Tags: database-design

I am new to database design and despite my research I can really only find basic examples on design which does not help for my situation.

Currently using MySQL

The problem I have is as follows:

I am building a site to manage aircraft information, then display that information and how it changes in the form of graphs (things like air speed, plane speed, wing tilt, ect ect).

At the moment I get all this data in CSV form, but different planes give different data (for example one plane might not have wing tilt).

At the moment all I have set up is a table with userID, username, and password.

The concept I do not understand is how I can store something like planeSpeed, especially since it would be a bunch of numbers because it is over the course of the flight (it gets a value every minute).

Also some users would have multiple planes.

So I am stuck visualizing this as a column would be airspeed and then have a ton of numbers in it?

Or would I somehow build a separate table for each plane and instead of userID I would have time?

Very unsure how to design this, any help or tips would be a huge help, sorry for sounding so inexperienced have never built more than a simple login before.

Comment: As a simple example lets take "airspeed" table - it will have columns (aircraft_id, time, airspeed) - aircraft_id is number referencing row in table of planes (there is "static" info about the aircraft - type, age, user...), time is the time of airspeed measurement and airspeed is the value - for each plane you have lot of rows, one for each time, storing one value. If you get multiple data each minute, you can extend that table with another columns (height, latitude, longitude...), thats ok, but each row contains only data of one specific time for one given plane. You will have many rows :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user1786423 said in your question's comment, you will probably have a `User` table, an `Aircraft` table and a table for each type of measurement.

As a minimum, `User` would have an id, say `idUser`. I'd imagine there would be more static data about a user in there as well.

As a minimum, `Aircraft` would have an id, say `idAircraft`, and `idUser`. `idUser` would reference `User.idUser`. I'd imagine there would be more static data about an aircraft in there as well.

The `AirspeedMeasurement` table would have, based on your descriptions, columns like `idAirspeedMeasurement`, `idAircraft`, `time`, `airSpeed`. `idAircraft` would reference `Aircraft.idAircraft`.

You may want to have a parent table for all of the measurements. For example, an `AircraftMeasurement` table would have the columns `idAircraftMeasurement`, `idAircraft`, `time`. Then, the child tables would have a primary key that references `idAircraftMeasurement`, and wouldn't have to each store `idAircraft` and `time`.

An ER diagram would look something like this:
[image]

Some sample data:

In this example Aircraft 1 records `PlaneSpeedMeasurement`s and `WingTiltMeasurement`s, whilst Aircraft 2 only records `PlaneSpeedMeasurement`s.
[image]

Let us know if something is unclear : ]

Comment: I would use separate tables for each measurement only in case you can get different set of measurements at different times. But I would personally prefer one table with nullable columns unless there were some reasons against it.

Comment: Does the layout let the user search by time? I understand everything except the way AircraftMeasurment is set up, don't quite understand the point of that table. Also just to confirm these are child tables right? I would then JOIN them later in query.

Comment: Yes, you can search by time, for example:

`SELECT * FROM AircraftMeasurement WHERE timeOfMeasurement = [some time]`

Yes, `AirSpeedMeasurement`, `WingTiltMeasurement`, and `PlaneSpeedMeasurement` are child tables of `AircraftMeasurement`. There are a couple of reasons you would have the `AircraftMeasurement` parent table - 1) it abstracts out the common fields (`idAircraft`, `timeofMeasurement`) 2) it would be possible to make a foreign key to any `AircraftMeasurement`, if that was ever needed.

Yes, you would need to join the parent with the child tables to get all the data.

Comment: You can of course not do the parent-child table approach if you want. Just remove the `AircraftMeasurement` table and place the `idAircraft` and `timeOfMeasurement` columns in each of the child tables.

Comment: @user1786423 I see that as being viable too.

Comment: @user1786423 I created a separate answer for your suggestion, hopefully you don't mind?

Comment: @JoeBorysko no problem, you put more work into it than I did with my comments

Answer (score 0):

As user1796423 suggested, you can combine the different aircraft measurement tables into one table. This would make most sense if the different measurements were all coming in at the same time. The columns representing measurement values would have to be nullable if they are given by some aircraft and not others.

Here's what the diagram would look like:

[image]

Here's some sample data:

Aircraft 1 gives `wingTilt`, `planeSpeed`, and `airSpeed` whilst Aircraft 2 only gives `planeSpeed` and `airSpeed`.
[image]